# import Tensorflow works but does not import anything

Tags: python, tensorflow

I followed the install from this page : 
https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0-rc/

Had no issues for all the steps, installed CUDA 8.0 and Cudnn5.1 before hand. (Couldn't specify 5.1 during the configure of TensorFlow, so I said 5)

I am not using anaconda or a virtual environment.

Here is what I'm getting :

I pointed towards python3.5, so I launch python3 in command line, import tensorflow as tf, try to run the example from the webpage (or on the tensorflow website: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup#test_the_tensorflow_installation), and I get errors such as : 

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'InteractiveSession'
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'`

My guess is it can't find any of the submodules of tensorflow, and when I do dir(tf) I get : 
['**doc**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**']
Which I'm guessing is way less than it should.

This is very similar to an issue on github of tensorflow : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3369

But it hasn't helped me. 
I've removed the tensorflow folder and reinstalled couple times, I didn't try to re install CUDA cause I don't think the problem comes from there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like someone else had a similar problem following that tutorial: https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0-rc/#comment-83

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid, but did you follow this comment suggestion in the final step of the tutorial? 

`$ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow
# with no spaces after tensorflow hit tab before hitting enter to fill in blanks`

The actual command is something more like: 

`$ sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.12.0rc1-py2-none-any.whl`

Comment: @ShanCarter Pretty sure I did. I managed to get it working by taking pieces out of other tutorials and redoing the whole steps again, maybe I screwed up along the way. Thanks for the help, I'll close the issue !

Answer (score 1):

Between the initial tutorial, the Tensorflow Install page and this other tutorial : http://withr.me/install-tensorflow-ubuntu-16-04/  ,  I managed to install Tensorflow with Python 3.5.

Unfortunately I don't have a clear idea how I did it, I just took pieces from the three parts.